# How to unable Ajax categories in back office on Prestashop 1.5

Tags: prestashop

I want to disable ajax on Treeview categories on "AdminProduct" (back office of PRESTASHOP 1.5).

I need to shown all categories at time.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but in the back office - moduls - Categories block you have the option to disable "Activate dynamic (animated) mode for sublevels.".

I believe that might be what you are looking for.

Good luck